# MDB Deploys Successfully: Then Won't Even Write to System.out. Why?

Tags: jms, message-queue, wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

I have a Java EE project that ran with WF-8 w/ HornetMQ:
--- Sever side was deployed as an .ear package.
--- Client side is a Java GUI that communicated with the server via JMS messaging.

It all worked when put away.

I’m trying to resurrect it using WF-10 w/ ArtemisMQ, and it’s killing me.

After clearing all the Exceptions dealing with Hornet -> Artemis, here’s where I am:

--- WF Console confirms gotest.ear deploys with no Exceptions. (Console out put on startup pasted below)

--- Client’s Eclipse console output confirms it has a Connection and that it sent an Object  Message. (my formatted output is pasted below)

--- Standalone-full.xml shows the Queue my MDB listens to configured.  AND WF browser console double confirms it. (Info on WF’s configuration also pasted below)

But my MDB will not write or log to the WF console at all. I.e. not even from its constructor method.  And there is no response at all from it's onMessage () to messages sent from the Client.

I’m helpless, because I don’t get Exceptions anywhere to hint at what’s wrong.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
Help!!

MDB CODE 
(I’ve cut it to the bone until I can get it to write or log to the WF console acknowledging it is hearing messages.)

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.ActivationConfigProperty;
import javax.ejb.MessageDriven;
import javax.ejb.MessageDrivenContext;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig ={  
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"), 
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="jms/queue/sendToServerQueue"),
      @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
      })

public class GoMsgBean implements MessageListener {

  final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GoMsgBean.class.getName());

  public GoMsgBean () {
    System.out.println("System.out message FROM GoMsgBean Constructor");
    logger.info("Logger message FROM GoMsgBean Constructor");
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void myInit () {
    System.out.println("System.out message FROM GoMsgBean PostConstruct");
    logger.info("Logger message FROM GoMsgBean PostConstruct");
      }

  public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    System.out.println("System.out message FROM GoMsgBean onMessage()");
    logger.info("Logger message FROM GoMsgBean onMessage()");
  }
}
```

STANDALONE-FULL.XML

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
  <server name="default">
  . . .
    <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
    <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
    <jms-queue name="SendToServerQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/sendToServerQueue"/>
    <jms-queue name="SendToClientQueue2" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/sendToClientQueue2"/>
    . . .
    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
    <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
  </server>
</subsystem>
```

**WFLY localhost :9990 Console Configuration Details**

```
Queues/Topics
Name:         SendToServerQueue
JNDINames:    java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/sendToServerQueue
**Durable?:   true**
Selector:     <blank>

Connection Factories
Name          InVmConnectionFactory
JNDI          java:/ConnectionFactory

Name:         RemoteConnectionFactory 
JNDI          java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory

Security Settings
Pattern       #
Role          guest

Address Settings
Pattern       #

Diverts       No Items!
```

ECLIPSE CONSOLE OUTPUT (when client GUI opens)
(I’ve added an insane number of System.out.printlns to track what’s happening line by line.  Each output string is prefaced by the Class.method () that’s writing the line.)

```
ECLIPSE CONSOLE OUTPUT when Client is opened

MsgCtrSnd.run ()       beg
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Requesting InitialContext
        CONNECTION VARIABLES
        key: java.naming.provider.url         value: http-remoting://localhost:8080
        key: java.naming.factory.initial      value: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
        key: java.naming.security.principal   value: jmsUser
        key: java.naming.security.credentials value: jmsUser123!
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       InitialContext OK: javax.naming.InitialContext@4135c3b
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Look up ConnectionFactory with: "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       ConnectionFactory: Ok:
                         org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Instantiating Connection
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       JMS Connection OK:
                         org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection@4d5d943d
Instantiating Session
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       JMS Session OK: 
                         ActiveMQSession->ClientSessionImpl 
                         [name=212aa734-90f5-11e7-aa7a-a3fb7876c1f2, username=appUser, closed=false, factory = org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl@2a4fb17b, metaData=(jms-session=,)]@368f2016
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Lookup Queue w/ JNDI name: ["jms/queue/sendToServerQueue"]
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Queue secured: 
                         ActiveMQQueue[SendToServerQueue]IS NOT NULL
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Instantiating Message Producer
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Message Producer [IS NOT NULL] 
                         ActiveMQMessageProducer->org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl@59474f18
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       Starting jmsConnection
  MsgCtrSnd.run ()       JMS Send Connection : Ok.
MsgCtrSnd.run ()       end

ECLIPSE CONOSOLE OUTPUT (when client GUI is used to send message to log in)

Cntrl.executeMenuAction ()    beg
  Cntrl.executeMenuAction ()    Switching to: Log In
  Cntrl.loginSend ()            beg
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            calling DataDialog.collectData()
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            EntityFieldsCollector ok
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            returned from DataDialog.collectData()
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            EntityFieldsCollector  contains 2 entries. 
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            key: Member ID:           308486  value:         ID
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            key: Member PW            308487  value:         PW
    Cntrl.loginSend ()            message center connection ok
    MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          beg
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          Action: Log In
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          clientHash: aaaaaa
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          memberId   : ID
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          memberPw   : PW
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          clientUserId   : null
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          clientUserPw   : null
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          calling createObjectMessage ()
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          ObjectMessage instantiated.
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()          Object Message object: java.util.ArrayList
      MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()        message sent.
    MsgCtrSnd.sendMsg ()        end
  Cntrl.loginSend ()          end
Cntrl.executeMenuAction ()  end
```

WILDFLY CONSOLE OUTPUT WHEN GOTEST.EAR IS DEPLOYED ON STARTUP

```
Calling "C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
Setting JAVA property to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: "C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final"

  JAVA: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java"

  JAVA_OPTS: "-Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"

===============================================================================

INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.5.2.Final
INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.6.Final
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) starting
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO version 3.4.0.Final
INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-3) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.4.0.Final
INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYIIOP0001: Activating IIOP Subsystem
INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYJSF0007: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.3.4.Final)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYWS0002: Activating WebServices Extension
INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 59) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 40) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 16 core threads with 128 task threads based on your 8 available processors
INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=4.9.6.Final
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.21.Final
INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver (version 1.5)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = mysql
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 128 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 32 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/jdbc/gotestdb]
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/jdbc/tappdb]
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYMSGAMQ0001: AIO wasn't located on this platform, it will fall back to using pure Java NIO.
WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "GoTest.ear" (runtime-name: "GoTest.ear")
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments
INFO  [org.wildfly.iiop.openjdk] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYIIOP0009: CORBA ORB Service started
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\journal,bindingsDirectory=C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\largemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\ProgramFilesGeo\Wildfly\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\activemq\paging)
INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-6) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.4.Final
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221013: Using NIO Journal
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "GoTest.jar")
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBWS022052: Starting JBossWS 5.1.5.Final (Apache CXF 3.1.6)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for GoTestDataBase
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'GoTest.ear/GoTest.jar#GoTestDataBase'
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment GoTest.ear
INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: GoTestDataBase
        ...]
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for activemq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.2.4.Final
INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.10.Final}
INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221007: Server is now live
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 1.1.0.wildfly-017 [nodeID=e2b89808-fdf2-11e6-9f54-3956fe24eb2d]
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.SendToServerQueue
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.SendToClientQueue2
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) AMQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment GoTest.jar
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'EnrollerBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "GoTest.jar" of deployment "GoTest.ear"' are as follows:

        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/EnrollerBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.EnrollerBean
        java:app/GoTest/EnrollerBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.EnrollerBean
        java:module/EnrollerBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.EnrollerBean
        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/EnrollerBean
        java:app/GoTest/EnrollerBean
        java:module/EnrollerBean

INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ExiterBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "GoTest.jar" of deployment "GoTest.ear"' are as follows:

        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/ExiterBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.ExiterBean
        java:app/GoTest/ExiterBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.ExiterBean
        java:module/ExiterBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.ExiterBean
        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/ExiterBean
        java:app/GoTest/ExiterBean
        java:module/ExiterBean

INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'LoginerBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "GoTest.jar" of deployment "GoTest.ear"' are as follows:

        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/LoginerBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.LoginerBean
        java:app/GoTest/LoginerBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.LoginerBean
        java:module/LoginerBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.LoginerBean
        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/LoginerBean
        java:app/GoTest/LoginerBean
        java:module/LoginerBean

INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'LogouterBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "GoTest.jar" of deployment "GoTest.ear"' are as follows:

        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/LogouterBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.LogouterBean
        java:app/GoTest/LogouterBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.LogouterBean
        java:module/LogouterBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.LogouterBean
        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/LogouterBean
        java:app/GoTest/LogouterBean
        java:module/LogouterBean

INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ReplierBean' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "GoTest.jar" of deployment "GoTest.ear"' are as follows:

        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/ReplierBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.ReplierBean
        java:app/GoTest/ReplierBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.ReplierBean
        java:module/ReplierBean!org.america3.gotest.server.sessionbeans.ReplierBean
        java:global/GoTest/GoTest/ReplierBean
        java:app/GoTest/ReplierBean
        java:module/ReplierBean

INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (MSC service thread 1-5) Resource adaptor started
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-5) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatoractivemq-ra
INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSGAMQ0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-8) WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'GoTest.ear/GoTest.jar#GoTestDataBase'
INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0042: Started message driven bean 'GoMsgBean' with 'activemq-ra.rar' resource adapter
INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Envers integration enabled? : true
INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container

Member.<init>................................beg
  Member.<init>................................Hello World. See! I can Log messages again.
Member.<init>................................end

INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "GoTest.ear" (runtime-name : "GoTest.ear")
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 1) AMQ151000: awaiting topic/queue creation jms/queue/sendToServerQueue
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 10.1.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.2.0.Final) started in 5392ms - Started 691 of 931 services (430 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

WILDFLY CONSOLE OUTPUT AFTER DEPLOYEMENT THAT SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM.
Note: the next INFO line says the jms/queue/sendToServerQueue is NOT durable, while WF Console says its configured to be durable)

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 1) AMQ151001: Attempting to reconnect org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec(ra=org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter@78712571 destination=jms/queue/sendToServerQueue destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15)

This is in reference to J. R. Perkins below concerning whether there was a log4j.xml in the deployment. This is another excerpt from WF’s standalone-full.xml I use for logging if I can ever get my MDB to even write to System.out:

<profile>
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
      <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter><named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/></formatter>
    </console-handler>
    <console-handler name="MY-CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
      <formatter><named-formatter name="MY-PATTERN"/></formatter>
      <target name="System.out"/>
    </console-handler>
    <console-handler name="GOTEST-HANDLER">
      <level name="INFO"/>
        <formatter><named-formatter name="GOTEST-PATTERN"/></formatter>
    </console-handler>
    . . .
    <logger category="org.america3.gotest" use-parent-handlers="false">
      <level name="ALL"/>
      <handlers><handler name="GOTEST-HANDLER"/></handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
      <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
      <level name="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="sun.rmi">
      <level name="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
      <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers><handler name="CONSOLE"/><handler name="FILE"/></handlers>
    </root-logger>
    <formatter name="PATTERN">
      <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
      <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <formatter name="MY-PATTERN">
      <pattern-formatter pattern="MeMeMe%s%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <formatter name="GOTEST-PATTERN">
      <pattern-formatter pattern="%s%n"/>
    </formatter>
  </subsystem>
  . . . 
</profile>
```

Comment: Do you have a log4j configuration file in your deployment?

Comment: Hi James. No. I was saving that for another day. For now I configured my server side logging in the standalone-full.xml. And it worked. (Please see toward bottom of WF Console output above. Lines that begin with Member.<init> are logging output from another class - Member. So right now I'm still trying to find out why  my MDB will not even write to System.out.  My bet is that once I get my MDB to write to System.out it will log just like Member already does. So for now the problem remains. My MDB deploys. Then seems dead. And I don't even get an Exception to hint at what's wrong.

Comment: Those `Member` messages is what makes it look like there may be a log4j configuration file. Writing to standard out should look some like `INFO [stdout] MMember.<init>...`. Really the log output doesn't really match any of the patterns in the configuration unless you stripped the date off for brevity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is logged here:

```
INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 1) AMQ151000: awaiting topic/queue creation jms/queue/sendToServerQueue
```

In other words, the MDB is not fully activated because it can't find the destination "jms/queue/sendToServerQueue".  I believe this is because you haven't defined the JNDI bindings properly (since you've only defined an "exported" entry).  Try using this:

```
<jms-queue name="SendToServerQueue" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/sendToServerQueue java:/jms/queue/sendToServerQueue"/>
```

Things to do to diagnose issues like this:

1. Read the log carefully for helpful information.
2. Check the consumerCount of the queue from which the MDB is supposed to receive messages.  If it's 0 then it means there's a problem with the MDB.

Comment: I tried it. No luck.
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default"),
    ("jms-queue" => "SendToServerQueue")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"messaging-activemq\"),
    (\"server\" => \"default\"),
    (\"jms-queue\" => \"SendToServerQueue\")
]"
I tried looking for an example of an exported/local jndi for same Queue. Failed miserably.

Comment: Yes. I tried different seperators between the two jndi names - ";" and "," Now off to learn: 1) where "consumerCount" lives, and 2) how to add code to a comment like you did above. [Ok to mention that WF documentation is only readable by people who no longer need it?  grin ... like the folks writing it are so deeply immersed in its evolution from JBoss they can no longer conceive of such a thing as a "beginner". But that's just me w/ "Sour Grapes". Otherwise its so close I hope your still willing to help.  Please note: "trying" log line says its not durable. WF GUI Admin console says it is.

Comment: Last thing. I tried the local JNDI all by itself. IT WORKED! Sort Of.  On deployment the MDB constructor dumped dozens of messages the GUI Client had left hanging in the Queue. Both 1) to System.out statements in its constuctor, and 2) the logger statements in its constructor. But I still need to figure out how to make the Queue accessible to the remote GUI (exported) and MDB (local). So all that's required to answer the question is how to assign 2 jndi names to one Queue. Maybe CLI command?

Comment: Hi Justin. You were right. I'm humiliated. I slowed down. Double checks all my typing. and your 1st suggestion worked. Thank you. I've awarded the bounty. And I'll go hide (while wildly celebrating success). glb